# To Fix a jquery image slider?

Tags: jquery

I wanted to make an image slider with jquery
I have 5 jpg images and 2 png images (next and previous).
here is the asp.net and javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
$(".slider).jslider({ btnNext:".next", btnPrev:".prev"})
});

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
<img id="next" class ="next" src="n.png" /> <img id="prev" class ="prev" src="p.png" />
<div class="slider">
<ul>

<li><img class="slider" src="1.jpg" alt="image1" /></li>
<li><img class="slider" src="2.jpg" alt="image2" /></li>
<li><img class="slider" src="3.jpg" alt="image3" /></li>
<li><img class="slider" src="4.jpg" alt="image4" /></li>
<li><img class="slider" src="5.jpg" alt="image5" /></li>
</ul>

</div>
</div>
```

but it doesn't work: Only the previous png image is visible and the images are like in a vertical list.
the link for the slider.js is http://www.harryfinn.co.uk/youtube/jslider_tut/jslider.js

Please let me know how can I fix this.

Comment: There's a mistake on the third line. Should be `$(".slider")...`

Comment: @ grc : exactly there were mistakes in the css file,now it works fine,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like the problem is that you're not using a stylesheet.

Try adding the code below to the `<head>` section. It will link in the stylesheet from the tutorial. If this fixes the problem you'll probably want to make your own stylesheet.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.harryfinn.co.uk/youtube/jslider_tut/style.css">
```

Oh and read my comment about the mistake.